# sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: fails while app is in background

Tags: multithreading, ios8, grand-central-dispatch, reachability, sendasynchronousrequest

I am using internet availability check using  `NSURLConnection` but it fails to call success or error block:

```
- (void)isNetworkAvailableWithCallBack:(SuccessCallback)successBlock onFailure:(FailureCallback)failureBlock   {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData __unused *data, NSError *error){
            if (response != nil){
                NSLog(@"Connected");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    successBlock(YES);
                });
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    failureBlock(YES);
                });
                NSLog(@"Not Connected");
                [self presentError:error];

            }
        }];
    }
```

App works great when app is in foreground or loading first time. Off course my background multitasking is enabled. The issue starts when the following occurs:

Send the app to BG.
Wait some time...
The app get killed by the iOS.

When my app comes again from background to foreground, block gets called with following status code:

```
Code=-1001
```

Its a request time out error. but why it is not called whenever my app goes to background(happens not every time, something it works fine).

Is there any thing wrong in my code? And how i handle this.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable "Project Background Mode" in Capabilities.

Please refer attached screenshot

[image]